# This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84 - But I downloaded ChromeDriver v88

Tags: selenium, symfony, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a Symfony project in which I need to use Panther for testing.

For that, I need the chromeDriver corresponding to my version of Google Chrome.

Google chrome is up to date in its latest version: **Version 88.0.4324.104**

[image]

So I downloaded the ChromeDriver corresponding to version 88 of google chrome, on the ChromeDriver download site: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

[image]

Now when I run the tests with this version of ChromeDriver I get the following error:

`Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException : session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84`

If I run manually the ChromeDriver.exe, I can see : `Starting ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96`, so it's the good version

I don't understand why, since I have version 88 of Google Chrome, and the correct version of ChromeDriver

EDIT : Here is the answer :

I had this folder: **C:/webdrivers** with an old chromeDriver. Panther will first search in this folder, before going to look for the chromeDriver in the **project/drivers** folder

Comment: When the error message shows up, check on the Task Manager details tab, you'll see the actual chromeriver.exe running, right click open file location, note its path and find if there's a code somewhere that refer to that path

Comment: how are you specifying chromedriver path ?

Comment: check your environemtn varaible

Comment: Okay I have it, thank you! Panther should have automatically taken the ChromeDriver from my project's / drivers folder, but instead it took it from C: / webdrivers, since I had an older version. Weird. But now it's settled he takes the voucher, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this folder: **C:/webdrivers** with an old chromeDriver. Panther will first search in this folder, before going to look for the chromeDriver in the **project/drivers** folder